# Combinatorical problem with k-subsets of [n] with no consecutive elements

Tags: combinatorics

How many $k$-substes of $[n]$ do not contain consecutive elements.

I saw the resolution to this problem, but I didn't understand quite well.

Here is what they have:

- Line up k $S$ and  $(n-k)$  $R$ so that no $S$ are consecutive.
- The problem is ,now, equivalent to choose $k$ spaces between $n-k+1$  ($k$ spaces between $R$, in the front and in the end of the sequence)

The final answer is ${n-k+1 \choose k}$

Can someone give me a hint to what the author might have thought when solved this problem, or if you have a similarly good answer to this problem, expose it here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the elements in the subset in increasing order be labeled $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$.  Let $[n]=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$

Let us consider the variables $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_{k+1}$ defined as $y_1=x_1-1$, $y_2=x_2-x_1$, $y_3=x_3-x_2$, ..., $y_k=x_k-x_{k-1}$ and finally $y_{k+1}=n-x_k$.  That is to say, the variables $y_i$ count the number of empty spaces between each of the $x_i$, taking the extremes into account as well.

The condition that none of the elements in your set are consecutive is equivalent to $y_i\geq 2$ for all $i\in\{2,3,\dots,k\}$.  $y_1$ may equal zero as can $y_{k+1}$.

Notice that $y_1+y_2+\dots+y_k+y_{k+1} = (x_1-1)+(x_2-x_1)+(x_3-x_2)+\dots+(n-x_k) = n-1$

Now, one final change of variable, since we don't like working with lowerbounds of $2$, we prefer to work entirely with lowerbounds of zero or lower bounds of $1$, let us let $z_i = y_i-2$ for each $i\in\{2,3,\dots,k\}$ and let $z_1=y_1$ and $z_{k+1}=y_{k+1}$.

We have then $z_1+z_2+\dots+z_{k+1}=n-1-(k-1)\cdot 2$ and each $z_i\geq 0$.

This is in a known form for a stars-and-bars problem of counting number of non-negative integer diophantine solutions to a system with answer

$$\binom{(n-1-2\cdot(k-1)+(k+1)-1}{(k+1)-1}$$

Simplifying, $n-1-2k+2+k+1-1 = n-k+1$ giving:

$$\binom{n-k+1}{k}$$

Comment: A more direct bijection would result from setting $a_1 = x_1, a_2 = x_2 - 1, a_3 = x_3 - 2, \ldots, a_k = x_k - k + 1$.  (Picture could be "removing one chair from between each pair" versus "adding a chair between each pair" for the inverse bijection.)